# SQL - Northwind database - Display for each year, the customer who purchased the highest amount

Tags: sql, database, northwind

I'm trying to Display for each year, the customer who purchased the highest amount in Northwind database using SQL.

```
SELECT 
   YEAR(o.OrderDate) AS OrderYear, 
   MAX(od.Quantity) AS MaxQuantity
FROM
  Customers c 
  JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
  JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY 
  YEAR(o.OrderDate)
```

That's what I managed to do. I just need some help with displaying the customer id for each one of the years.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would make more sense to get the SUM rather than MAX per person for each year. Here we can use the row_number() function to rank people.

```
select orderYear, customerId, quantity
  from (
    select c.customerId, year(o.orderDate) as orderYear, 
      sum(od.quantity) as quantity, 
      row_number() over (partition by year(o.orderDate) order by sum(od.quantity) desc) as rn
    from customers c
    join orders o
      on c.customerId = o.customerId
    join order_details od
      on o.orderId = od.orderId
    group by c.customerId, year(o.orderDate)
    )z
where rn = 1
order by 1
```

If you really want MAX, then replace SUM with MAX in both occurrences.

Comment: Thank you ! Can you just tell me what does the z below the "group by" means?

Comment: It's an alias for a sub-query, required by some DBMS, including sql server.